# Traverse/Transform the expression tree

Tags: java, c#, algorithm, tree

I have an expression tree that I need to traverse and generate a certain string.
Lets say I have this tree

```
     OR
    /  \
  AND   C
 /   \
A     B
```

And I want to transform it into :

```
(A AND B) OR C
```

I was thinking to use in order traversal, but that's not exactly what I will gonna need.

Comment: You want to implement in java or c# or just algorithm ?? user proper tags

Comment: What is wrong with an in order traversal, in your opinion?

Comment: @Panther language doesn't really matter even pseudo code would be fine

Comment: @rici It is not visiting nodes in right order and please note that here not all nodes are containing values,

Comment: In your example it is the right order. some nodes are operators and they correctly are visited between their left and right children. So where is the issue? Do we mean different things by in-order?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution prints redundant parentheses:

```
Visit(node):
  Output "("
  If node.has_left():
    Visit(node.left)
  Output node.label
  If node.has_right():
    Visit(node.right)
  Output ")"
```

To fix the redundant parenthesis problem, assign each operator a left- and right-precedence, just as in operator precedence parsing, and pass the parent node's precedence into the visit. The visit then outputs parentheses only if the visited node's precedence is lower than the passed in precedence from the parent node.

Answer (score 0):

```
abstract class Expression {
}

class Binary extends Expression {

    final String operator;
    final Expression left, right;

    Binary(String operator, Expression left, Expression right) {
        this.operator = operator;
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("(%s %s %s)", left, operator, right);
    }
}

class Variable extends Expression {

    final String name;

    Variable(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}

@Test
public void testExpression() {
    Expression e = new Binary("OR", new Binary("AND", new Variable("A"), new Variable("B")), new Variable("C"));
    System.out.println(e);
    // -> ((A AND B) OR C)
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if I can see any traversal here

Comment: The traversal is in the implicit recursive call to `Binary.toString`. Inside that method, the arguments to `String.format` are converted to Strings.